# High ping in emulator

Tags: networking, android-emulator

I want to play mlbb on pc android emulator since it does not run on android x86. I have 70~90 ping on my network. But i am getting more than 150 in emulator. I tried switching netork mode and used bluestac and nox. But no difference. Why is my emulator ping high?

Pc:
Cpu=core i3 6100
Gpu=gtx 1050 ti
ram=4gb(8gb page)

Comment: Have you checked the CPU usage while playing? Your CPU is a five years old dual core, torturing it with an ARM emulator does not make it better. Even on a recent very fast CPU an ARM emulator is typically slower than a middle class real phone.

Comment: But the game runs smooth

Comment: An emulator uses a virtual network, this means that the CPU has to process each sent/received packet multiple time (one time for each virtual component). If the CPU is highly utilized the time increases before each packet can be processed. Hence the latency increases. However because of all the involved virtual network components the latency always increases compared to a native network access. But having a slow CPU additionally increases the latency.